# Eclipse: Can't explore my projects, resources file can't generate

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I'm learning, been so for about a month now.

I started on google maps yesterday, then my project explorer went on the fritz.

It won't let me explore my source files, or my resource files.
I deleted my copy of eclipse and installed a new one, still nothing.

[image]

I can't explore my source, can't even see my resource files.

How can I fix this?

Comment: i like your question, should give you the score for posting images now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to the menu on top: **Window->Show View-> Package Explorer**.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I sure feel like a boob. Thanks this managed to fix my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Under the "Window" tab you can open a perspective/view. You can open the Project Explorer view from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at the image you posted, it seems like you haven't set the ADT path yet (both Android SDK Manager and Android Virtual Device Manager aren't showing).

**Window -> Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location**